# Ordering values from most to least in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to retrieve the table value in order of from most to least. 
For example, if we had a single column table like the following,

```
selected_val
    2
    3
    3
    2
    1
    3
    1
    1
    1
    4
```

I need a SQL that will return the values in the order of 1, 3, 2, 4, because there are four 1's, three 3's, two 2's, and one 4 in the table. I only need distinct values, which means I don't want 1,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,4. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use grouping to achieve this:

```
SELECT selected_val
FROM mytable
GROUP BY selected_val
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

The trick here is to `ORDER BY` the row count of each group: descending ordering yields the `selected_val` having the greatest row count in the first place, then comes the second value, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could group by the value and order by `count(*)`:

```
SELECT   selected_val
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY selected_val
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```